# How to update codemagic environment variable during build process

Tags: android, firebase, cicd, codemagic

Is it possible to update environment variable during build process?
I need to increase code version before uploading apk to firebase.

I have found a case when you receive the last version from play store and increase it, but in my case I store version inside environment variables

Comment: are you working with `codemagic.yaml` file or Workflow Editor?

Comment: @MikhailTokarev with yaml

Answer (score 1):

with `codemagic.yaml` file there are 2 options:

1. if you need access in the same `script` block you just export the same variable with a new value

```
scripts:
  - name: set new value
    script: |
      export MY_VAR=foobar
      ./my_command.sh
```

2. you can also make a new value available to any subsequent steps

```
scripts:
  - name: set new value
    script: |
      echo "MY_VAR=foobar" >> $CM_ENV
  - name: use new value
    script: |
      ./my_command.sh
```

you can find more information in the doc https://docs.codemagic.io/yaml-basic-configuration/using-environment-variables/#setting-environment-variables-at-build-time